# How SSL server can select cipher suite from Client proposed parameter?

Tags: tls, openssl

When Client send list of cipher suites in client hello.. at that time server will select from one cipher suite. I want to know how it is selected?

Comment: Welcome to Security SE. Please tell us what research you've already done on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

The server checks which ciphers are offered by the client and are also supported by the server. From this it then select the final cipher. If this choice is more based on the clients preference (order of ciphers in the ClientHello) or on the servers preference depends on the server configuration, e.g. the `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` setting in nginx or similar settings in other servers.